# После изменения названия функции с 'main' на 'calculator' выводит ошибку ld return 1 exit status

Tags: c

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>


 int calculator()
{
    float first_number = 0, second_number = 0, total = 0 ;
    char sign;
    printf("Пример ввода калькулятора(5+3),(8*9),(7/3.7)\n");
    scanf("%f" "%c" "%f", &first_number, &sign, &second_number);
    char choice_quit;
    bool done =  true;
    while (done)
    {


        switch (sign)
        {

        case '+':
            total = first_number + second_number;
            printf("%.2f\n",total);
            break;


        case '-':

            total = first_number - second_number;
            printf("%.2f\n",total);
            break;

        case '*':
            total = first_number * second_number;
            printf("%.2f\n",total);
            break;

        case '/':
            total = first_number / second_number;
            printf("%.2f\n",total);
            break;

        }

        scanf("%f" "%c" "%f", &first_number, &sign, &second_number);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А ну-ка, вспомните, что такое функция `main()`? Чем она выделяется среди всех остальных?

Comment: Так а что у вас стало выполнять роль `main` после изменения имени?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В обычном, в том числе Вашем случае, если компилировать без дополнительных условий и комманд компилятору, такая программа не будет иметь точки входа, то есть не будет понятно с какой инструкции начинать выполнение Вашей программы.

Следовтельно, проще всего изменить название Вашей функции `Calculator()` обратно на `main()`.

Если Вы все же хотите иметь в Вашей программе функцию `Calculator()`, можете создать ее как отдельную функцию и вызывать ее внутри тела функции `int main()` или `void main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Программы на C и С++ не работают без функции main :)

Comment: Они могут работать без функции под названием main, если в настройках компилятора изменить точку входа. Также, если вы создаете dll, то в ней будет находится DllMain, а не main. В любом случае есть какой-то аналог.